# table relation size is very large compared to sum of column size

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql 9.6.

I have a psql table with the following schema :-

```
user_id: bigInt
post: jsonb
```

Now when I run the following query:-

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('user_content'));
```

It is returning :-
199 GB

I have postgresql 9.6.
But when I run the following query:-

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(user_content.*))) FROM user_content;
```

it returns

79 MB

Can anyone help me why this table table is taking so much space while actual column size is not that large?

And how to solve this problem?

Comment: What I’ve understood is that `pg_column_size` doesn’t count the toast sizes and if you have big data in the JSON it’ll be in the toast table. Can’t find a definite source for this though

Comment: So can let help me what queries should I run and output that would help you to know the reason of this problem? Please help me as the prod Db is growing at a size of 2gb every half hr.

Comment: `pg_total_relation_size()` includes the size of all indexes. What does `pg_relation_size()`  report for that table

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It counts TOAST size.

Comment: Apart from the indexes, there is metadata per page and row, and there is perhaps padding between the columns. Moreover, your table could be bloated.

Comment: pg_relation_size() returns 888 kB

Comment: I did vaccum cleaning and the table returned back to the original size. But it start expanding again. My jsonb column is update extensive? Does psql keeps dead rows on every update ?